# Yii ajax return html page

Tags: html, ajax, yii

there! I have a problem with receive data from my ajax query. It's return html code of the page.

My ajax code

```
         $.ajax({
         url: 'index.php?r=site/page&view=mail',
         type: 'post',
         data: {action: 'smtp_save', smtp_login: login, smtp_password: password, smtp_server: server, smtp_port: port },
         success: function($output) {
            //debug message
         alert($output);          
         }
         })
```

Php, just for test only

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) 
{ 
   echo 'test'; 

}
```

Comment: try to remove `dataType : "html",` from your code

Comment: or change it to what you need like dataType:'json'

Comment: doesn't work, just forget to remove it from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect? of course it return HTML. If you do not set the return data type specifically, it tries to guess the dattatype.
And as you output only "test" so it is HTML of course.
If you want JSON you should do 2 things:

1. set the type to JSON with `dataType:'json'`
2. user this php code: `echo json_encode('test')`

And if you do this all in the controler/action, then you should add `Yii::app()->end();`
after the `echo`, otherwise Yii renders the whole page output. This way you only get what you have echod out

Comment: is it nescceary to set dataType ?

Comment: @RakeshShetty - it may not be needed, but it is safer this way, so you are 100% sure you get json